# Paint an Object (I know this sounds ridiculous)

Tags: materials

I honestly can't figure out how to paint the default cube in blender.  I can do alot.  I am comforable with adding textures.  But I just want to paint the cube.
I have watched numerous tutorials but none of them are working for me. 
I gather that I need to click on the cube and then add material and go from there.
I have succesfully added textures to objects but can not for the life of me figure this out.
Every tutorial I watch has a completely different layout (older version) and it's not working.
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you want to go to the texture paint tab. Press new image and name it something so you could recognize it.[image]
2. Go to the shading tab and assign an image texture to base color. In the dropdown, select your created paint image.
   [image]
3. Now the image is assigned to the object. It should be black by default. Go back to the texture paint tab and you should be able to paint now. Press n to change color, size, and strength. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to post a question to figure something out.  I had been trying to solve this for a week and then figured out problem as soon as I posted.
I had to switch to cycles to see the color change.  Not sure why?
Thank you!

Comment: Hello, please don't use the Your Answer field, it is made to answer your question, not to comment. To comment, use "add a comment"  ;)